# Display all form errors in twig symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I have form which contains collectiontype (field `col`).

On field in collectiontype(call it `a`), I have validator which return errors.

I try with `{{form_errors(form)}}` and `{{form_errors(form.col)}}` but they aren't working...

Comment: are you sure you pass in your validators ?

Comment: can you show your controller code?  if you just validate the object, then it doesn't gives you errors. You have to validate your form .

http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#using-the-validator-service

Comment: Errors return by validator works fine because `{{form_rest(form)}}` render errors with inputs

Answer (score 0):

I typically do:

```
{% if form.col.vars.errors|length %}
<span>
    {{ form.col.vars.errors }}
</span>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `{{ form_errors(form.col) }}` does  not display errors (look at my question)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [FormErrorsSerializer](https://github.com/temenb/FormErrorsSerializer) to get the all errors and return it  as JSON array  , this code snip from a project i'm working on it

```
function addOwnership(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get('land_id');
    $land = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DamanBundleCoreBundle:Land')->find($id);
    $ownership = new OwnershipHistory();
    $ownership_form = $this->createForm('Daman\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\OwnershipType', $ownership);
    $ownership_form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($ownership_form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($ownership_form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $ownership->setLandId($land);
            $em->persist($ownership);
            $em->flush();
            $response = array('success' => true,
                'msg' => $this->get('translator')->trans('data_has_been_successfully_added'),
                'id' => $ownership->getId(),
                'action' => 'refresh'
            );

        } else {
            $errors = $this->get('form_serializer')->serializeFormErrors($ownership_form, true, false);
            $response = array('success' => false, 'msg' => $this->get('translator')->trans('error_exist_in_the_form'), 'errors' => $errors);

        }
        $jsonResponse = new JsonResponse($response);
        return $jsonResponse;

    }


}//end function
```